# Is there a way to load the ShowConfig before Sitecore finishes initializing?

Tags: configuration

I am currently setting up a production environment and I keep running into exceptions thrown while the site is initializing, due to configuration/patching issues. The fact that I can't load the *ShowConfig* is slowing me down and I would be able to troubleshoot and fix these issues a lot faster if I could only see it. Is there any way for me to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the [Sitecore Config Builder](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/modules/sitecore_configbuilder.aspx) tool which is available on the Marketplace.

[image: Sitecore Config Builder]

Select the **web.config** for the solution and then choose where to save the resulting merged config file. This is the same result as you would see if you browsed to `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` but it does not require a working Sitecore instance, just the config files. This is extremely useful if you want to see final patched config for a production instance from backups or without having to set it up locally for exmaple.

The Config Builder tool is also installed and accessible if you have [Sitecore Instance Manager](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/modules/sitecore_instance_manager.aspx) installed:

[image: Sitecore Instance Manager]

Comment: Very cool! So this actually installs on the actual machine, as opposed to the instance?

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel: It's just a few files, you can put it on a USB stick if you want, no install required. You can copy it up to the PROD instance or just copy the PROD config files down locally and run it there.

Comment: That's reeeeeeeeeally cool! I would upvote again, if I could!

Answer (score 7):

You can get the value of the fully patched Sitecore config by updating your *Global.asax* file to the following:

```cs
<%@Application Language='C#' Inherits="Sitecore.Web.Application" %>
<script runat="server">
protected void Application_Start()
{
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText("<website_root>\\App_Data\\sitecore.config", Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetConfiguration().OuterXml);
}
</script>
```

This tells the application to write the fully patched Sitecore config to the *\App_Data* folder of your site's webroot. You can, of course, change this location to one of your choice.